# Reading and displaying a file but output is incorrect

Tags: c++

I have this file:

```
###BEGIN

Player

FName: Jens

LName: Hogh

Club: Aalborg

Player

FName: Sebastian

LName: Perez

Club: Monaco

###COMPLETE
```

I have to read it and display it.
This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string txt[300];
    

    int i=0;
    ifstream file ("example.txt");
    std::string line;
    while (std:: getline (file, line)) 
    {
        std:: cout << line; /* use `line' inside the while-loop. */ 
    } 


 
    return 0;
}
```

The output is incorrect! it is displaying this :

#### BEGINPlayerFName: JensLName: HoghClub: AalborgPlayerFName: SebastianLName: PerezClub: Monaco###COMPLETE

Its all squished together. How do I get it to be separated and look like the file above?

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout << line;` you never tell the program to print a newline try `std::cout << line << '\n';`

Also you specify at the beginning of your file `using namespace std;` which means you dont need to put `std::` before the built in functions anymore. So `std::cout` could be rewritten as just `cout`